# Unknown property 'grid-template-columns' in atom

Tags: html, css, css-grid, atom-editor

I am new to CSS and web-development in general. I am trying to learn on Atom, but it won't allow me to compile the CSS code. I am confident there is no problem with the code itself, since it runs well on online editors. But atom gives me `Unknown property 'grid-template-columns'` message.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box a">A</div>
  <div class="box b">B</div>
  <div class="box c">C</div>
  <div class="box d">D</div>
  <div class="box e">E</div>
  <div class="box f">F</div>
</div>
```

The CSS stylesheet:

```
body {
  margin: 40px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
}

.box {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 150%;
}
```

[image]

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you are using `linter-csslint` which outputs the warning on the screenshot. Unfortunately, it does not support modern CSS features such as grid. The cause is likely its dependency on CSSLint, which hasn't been updated in years. You should probably use a different linter, e.g. one that's based on [stylelint](https://atom.io/packages/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=linter%20stylelint&commit=Search).